# simulate change not working with trim() enzyme

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I was using this test when I had a bug, so I used the trim function for resolve it, and the these test fail, tried in different ways but didn't found the solution

```js
const generalWrapper = shallow(<AddVehiclesTable {...generalProps} />)
const generalInstance = generalWrapper.instance()

describe('onSearchChange', () => {
    test('should change the "search" state', () => {
        const theFilterValue = 'a new filter value'
        generalWrapper.find('.filter-input').simulate('change', { target: { value: theFilterValue } })

        const expectedState = Object.assign({}, generalInstance.state)
        expectedState.searchValue = { 'target': { 'value': theFilterValue } }
        expect(generalInstance.state).toEqual(expectedState)
        expect(generalInstance.state.userInteractedWithComponent).toBe(true)
    })
})
```

```js
onSearchChange (searchValue) {
    const value = searchValue.trim()
    this.setState({ searchValue: value, userInteractedWithComponent: true })
}
```

Error message

> TypeError: searchValue.trim is not a function

Any suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function gets the Object as a parameter.
Expose field that you needed

I don't see the whole picture, but can guess that you need something like

```
onSearchChange ({ target: { value: incomeValue } }) {
    const value = incomeValue.trim()
    this.setState({ searchValue: value, userInteractedWithComponent: true })
}
```